# Making a jQuery Isotope layout initialize inside a Bootstrap Tab

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I have a bootstrap tab control with 4 tabs. My Isotope code is inside the 3rd tab. But when I navigate to that tab, the layout is not engaged (All the images are on their own line, not in a nice tiled layout). If I resize the page it will reorganize into the proper layout.

I have recreated the issue here. http://jsfiddle.net/Vc6Vk/

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
   ....isotope code here
</div>
```

How do you make the Isotope engage so that when I navigate to the tab, it is already formatted and displaying correctly?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the event shown.bs.tab :

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $container.isotope('layout');
});
```

This code will trigger `layout` for all tabs, so you can detect the tab with e.target, if e.target == your tab link to your isotope grid, then trigger `layout`. Hope it makes sense...

http://jsfiddle.net/Vc6Vk/1/

Comment: This works great, any idea for the best way to keep the CSS animation from firing when you land on that tab? Id prefer the animation to only happen if the screen is resized?

Comment: We can't use display:none so we will need to set the container visibility to hidden, then reLayout, then set it to visible again when isotope is done making the grid: http://jsfiddle.net/Vc6Vk/2/

Comment: There's a small issue, that once you go to the tab, then select another and go back it is now hidden. But aside from that the additional few milliseconds the visibility takes to engage is less attractive to me than the original short css animation. Might just keep it as it was with the animation. Im not super into javascript, so its a little difficult to modify your code. :)

Comment: Sorry, haven't thought about this case, I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Vc6Vk/3/ but I do agree that the small delay with visibility is less attractive :)

Comment: Just incase anyone else comes across this problem. One solution I found for the animation issue is to just flat out remove the isotope transition-animation in the CSS and set it to 0s. Both solutions have there pros and cons :/ Im super happy with the result so far but if anyone else had any ideas id be willing to try and perfect this.

Answer (score 6):

The answer by Karine is great but it might not work in recent versions because the method "reLayout" has been renamed to "layout".

So instead of

```
$('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('.grid').isotope('reLayout');
});
```

please use

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('.grid').isotope('layout');
});
```