# Why did this Javascript file stop working (in Wordpress)?

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-isotope

I have this small function to reload an isotope layout inside Bootstrap tabs when they're activated (taken from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214362/making-a-jquery-isotope-layout-initialize-inside-a-bootstrap-tab))

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
    $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
    alert("Somethings happening");
    $('.b5-file-manager.b5-list').isotope('layout');
    });
});
```

Initially this solution wasn't working for me, but after using a few different selectors to narrow down my targeting (and try and make sure nothing funny was going on) this then began to work. I deleted the alert, as my script was now working, but then the `layout` stopped firing.

This is in use in a WordPress child theme, but is enqueued correctly in the child theme functions.php, and is loading in the page OK. I think it may be something to do with when the script loads as it was working. I have an example page here [in my test build](http://test.citychurchworc.org.uk.gridhosted.co.uk/1373-2/) (sorry, I know this isn't good SO practice, but its the best place to see it an action)

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Any errors in the browser's console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There might be some error about `$`.

Wrap your code in IIFE syntax:

```
(function($){
    //put all code here
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: thank you, that works. I've just done a quick read up on IIFE, but its not clear to me how it makes a difference. Could you give a quick overview? (Sorry, I'm no programmer!)

Comment: That's create a scope for specific one to run it. It's more like a safe container which saves different cars to collide with the global ones.

Answer (score 0):

The quotes around tab may be causing the issue. Try this:

```
$('a[data-toggle=&quot;tab&quot;]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
```