# initialize multiple instances of isotope in separate tabs. The tabs break isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-isotope

I have multiple instances of isotope running in separate tabs. Isotope functions just fine in one tab, but when i switch tabs my footer is overlaying the isotope container. it does this until i click on one of the isotope filter options. once i click one, then the footer gets pushed down. However, when i go back to the previous tab - this tab is now messed up. here are some screenshots to show what I mean.

this is what it should look like. and this is what the loads loads as
[image: originally should look like this]
this is what it ends up looking like when i switch tabs. then if i click on "all" it goes back to normal (i guess this is where isotope turns on?) and if i go back to the first tab. it's broken like this section bad was.
[image: this is what it looks like when i go to a new tab]

here is my html and jquery

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    loadCSS("https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro");
    loadCSS("https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.6.3/css/font-awesome.min.css");
    // filtr menu
    var navbutton = $('navbutton');

    navbutton.on('click', function() {

        $(this).siblings().removeClass('open').end().addClass('open');

    });

    var $grid = $('.grid').isotope({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        percentPosition: true,
        masonry: {
            columnWidth: '.grid-sizer'
        }
    });

    // layout Isotope after each image loads
    $grid.imagesLoaded().progress(function() {
        $grid.isotope('layout');
    });

    $('#filters').on('click', 'navbutton', function() {
        var filtr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({
            filter: filtr
        });
    });

    $('#filters2').on('click', 'navbutton', function() {
        var filtr = $(this).attr('data-filter');
        $grid.isotope({
            filter: filtr
        });
    });
  
  $(function(){
  $('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');
  $('.block article').hide();
  $('.block article:first').show();
  $('ul.tabs li').on('click',function(){
    $('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
    $('.block article').hide();
    var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
    $(activeTab).show();
    return false;
  });
});

});
```

```html
<!-- Image portfolio -->
<!--- tabs --->
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class ="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">
<ul class="tabs">
    <li data-toggle="tab"><a href="#tab1">Interior</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab2" data-toggle="tab">Furniture</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tab3" data-toggle="tab">Environment</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
</div>
</div>
  <!--- end tabs --->
   <section class="block">
<article id="tab1">
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class = "row">
    <div class ="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

      <!-- image Filter -->
      <gallery-filter id="filters">
    <navbutton data-filter=".bedroom">Bedroom</navbutton>
  <navbutton data-filter=".kitchen">Kitchen</navbutton>
<navbutton data-filter=".livingroom">Living Room</navbutton>
<navbutton data-filter=".other">Other</navbutton>
<navbutton class="open" data-filter="*">All</navbutton>
</gallery-filter>
<gallery-filter id="filters4">
<navbutton class="open description">filter</navbutton>
</gallery-filter>
<!-- image filter end -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- Gallery -->
<div class = "row">
<div class ="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="grid" id="filters">
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="grid-item bedroom">

<!-- images go here -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of gallery -->
</div>
</article>

<article id="tab2">
<div class="container-fluid">
<div class = "row">
  <div class ="col-md-8 col-md-offset-2">

    <!-- image Filter -->
    <gallery-filter id="filters2">
  <navbutton data-filter=".chair">Chairs</navbutton>
<navbutton data-filter=".table">Tables</navbutton>
<navbutton data-filter=".dresser">Dressers</navbutton>
<navbutton data-filter=".bed">Beds</navbutton>
<navbutton class="open" data-filter="*">All</navbutton>
</gallery-filter>
<gallery-filter id="filters3">
<navbutton class="open description">filter</navbutton>
</gallery-filter>
<!-- image filter end -->
</div>
</div>
<!-- Gallery -->
<div class = "row">
<div class ="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
<div class="grid" id="filters2">
<div class="grid-sizer"></div>
<div class="grid-item chair">

<!-- images go here -->

</div>
</div>
</div>
<!-- end of gallery -->
</div>
</article>
</section>
<!-- End Image portfolio -->
```

while looking through stack overflow i found this post: [Making a jQuery Isotope layout initialize inside a Bootstrap Tab](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19214362/making-a-jquery-isotope-layout-initialize-inside-a-bootstrap-tab)

I tried out the code:

```
 $('a[data-toggle="tab"]').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
  $('.grid').isotope('layout');
});
```

but i was unsure what to replace `shown.bs.tab` with and couldn't get it working. since this code applies to the bootstrap tabs (which i am not using)

any help is appreciated. thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have same problem, I watch *Making a jQuery Isotope layout initialize inside a Bootstrap Tab* and try out but not work for me. and i found another solution for isotope in bootstrap tabs.

First of all you must create a *div* in your tab and **Initialize in HTML** isotope in  your div like this:

```
<div class="tab-pane" id="messages">
  <div class="grid-message" data-isotope='{"itemSelector": ".item-message" , "gutter":5 }'>
      <div class="item-message"></div>
      <div class="item-message"></div>
     ...
      </div>
  </div>
```

after that add this jquery code add to page for  reCreate layout when tab clicked

```
 $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".nav-tabs a").click(function () {
                $(this).tab('show');
            });
            $('.nav-tabs a').on('shown.bs.tab', function (e) {
                if (e.target.hash == '#messages') {
                    //for isotope
                    $('.grid-message').isotope('layout');
                }

                if (e.target.hash == '#Othertabs') {}
            });
        });
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Vc6Vk/38/

Answer (score 0):

You need to run layout when the tab is clicked. Try this:

```
$(function(){
$('ul.tabs li:first').addClass('active');
$('.block article').hide();
$('.block article:first').show();
$('ul.tabs li').on('click',function(){
$('ul.tabs li').removeClass('active');
$(this).addClass('active');
$('.block article').hide();
var activeTab = $(this).find('a').attr('href');
$(activeTab).show();
$grid.isotope('layout'); //add isotope layout here
return false;
});
});
```